# Where is the 'gettarget' macro definition in Android's build.xml

Tags: android, macros, build.xml

So Google went ahead and published a change to the build.xml Android uses in R20, deleting the classpath variable I was depending on in my project. Now it looks like it's using:

```
project.target.class.path
```

so I'm using this in my build.xml with the latest SDK tools installed on my machine, and everything is peachy on my end... but my remote Jenkins server no likey. To solve my problem on both ends I figured I'd just pull out the code that sets this attribute from the Android build.xml, and set my own property. The bit of code in the Android build.xml which appears to be setting this property is this chunk in the -build-setup target:

```
<gettarget
     androidJarFileOut="project.target.android.jar"
     androidAidlFileOut="project.target.framework.aidl"
     bootClassPathOut="project.target.class.path"
     targetApiOut="project.target.apilevel"
     minSdkVersionOut="project.minSdkVersion" />
```

I'm assuming this is a macro, but the whole chunk of code glows red brighter than Rudolph's nose in a snowstorm when I'm looking at it in IntelliJ. Where is this thing being defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gettarget is an Android ant task, com.android.ant.GetTargetTask.

My guess is that the gettarget task set the values for all the properties whose name passing in as parameters.